# Add relation related columns to many-to-many table flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following models:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, lazy='subquery',
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'), primary_key=True)
    db.Column('language', db.String(50), nullable=False)
)
```

Know if I want to make the following additions:

```
tag = Tag()
Page.tags.append(tag)
```

How to set the value for the `language` column for the new added tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that by creating `PageTagModel` model.

**like the following:**

```
class PageTagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pagetags'

    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pages.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)

    page = db.relationship('Page', backref=db.backref("pagetags"))
    tag = db.relationship('Tag', backref=db.backref("pagetags"))

    language = db.Column('language', db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

**And please edit the `Page` model to the following:**

```
class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I assume you gave the `Tag` model table this `tags` by using `__tablename__ = 'tags'` and `Page` model to `pages`.

Full picture:

```
class Page(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class PageTagModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'pagetags'

    page_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('pages.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), primary_key=True)

    page = db.relationship('Page', backref=db.backref("tags_annotation"))
    tag = db.relationship('Tag', backref=db.backref("tags_annotation"))

    language = db.Column('language', db.String(50), nullable=False)

 # to use it
 tag = Tag()
 page = Page()
 page_tags = PageTagModel(page=page, tag=tag, language='English')

 db.session.add(tag)
 db.session.add(page)
 db.session.add(page_tags)
 db.session.commit()
```

if you want to get `tags` directly from the `Page` model then you must add the following line to the `Page` model

```
tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary='pagetags', lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('pages', lazy=True))
```

Comment: Then how to use it, to set the language field?

Comment: And to get tags of a certain Page object, I should use tags or pagetags?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you can remove the `tags` from `Page` model.
Answered + Code updated.